# 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect' despite the code being identical right before it and working just fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I just need to get some sprites going on a game project, and I got one of them going but 2, 3 and, 4 are just refusing to work and are giving me the error, "'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'" Here is my code leading up to the error: It isn't all of my code, but hopefully enough to see the issue.

```
import pygame
 
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
score = 0
play = 0

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Player(Sprite):
    def update(self):
 
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers.
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 
        # Now see how the mouse position is different from the current
        # player position. (How far did we move?)
        diff_x = self.rect.x - pos[0]
        diff_y = self.rect.y - pos[1]
 
        # Loop through each block that we are carrying and adjust
        # it by the amount we moved.
 
        # Now wet the player object to the mouse location
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        self.rect.y = pos[1]
 
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

#class Sound():
    #def play(filename):
        #pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)


# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 750
screen_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption("LARP")
 
# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'Group.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
#TITLE SCREEN
title_image = pygame.image.load("title.png").convert_alpha()
quit_image = pygame.image.load("quit.png").convert_alpha()
logo_image = pygame.image.load("logo.png").convert_alpha()
background_image = pygame.image.load("title_screen.png").convert_alpha()
map_image = pygame.image.load("map.png").convert_alpha()
quit_block = pygame.sprite.Group()
start_block = pygame.sprite.Group()
Title = pygame.mixer.Sound("title_song.wav")
Map = pygame.mixer.Sound("map_song.wav")



#PLAYER
player_image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()

#CUTSCENES
cutscene_1 = pygame.image.load("cutscene_1.png").convert_alpha()
continue_button = pygame.image.load("cont.png").convert_alpha()
continue_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#NUMBERS
one = pygame.image.load("one.png").convert_alpha()
two = pygame.image.load("two.png").convert_alpha()
three = pygame.image.load("three.png").convert_alpha()
four = pygame.image.load("four.png").convert_alpha()
lvlselect = pygame.sprite.Group()

#OTHER
back_button = pygame.image.load("back.png").convert_alpha()
back_butt = pygame.sprite.Group()

# This is a list of every sprite.
# All blocks and the player block as well.
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
#for i in range(50):
     #This represents a block
    #block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)
 
     #Set a random location for the block
    #block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    #block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)
 
     #Add the block to the list of objects
    #block_list.add(block)
    #all_sprites_list.add(block)

#TITLE SCREEN
title = Sprite("title.png")
title.rect.x = 340
title.rect.y = 230
all_sprites_list.add(title)
start_block.add(title)
quitg = Sprite("quit.png")
quitg.rect.x = 340
quitg.rect.y = 350
all_sprites_list.add(quitg)
quit_block.add(quitg)
logo = Sprite("logo.png")
logo.rect.y = 90
logo.rect.x = 310
all_sprites_list.add(logo)
block_list.add(logo)

#CUTSCENE
continues = Sprite("cont.png")
continues.rect.x = 608
continues.rect.y = 466
continue_list.add(continues)

#NUMBERS
one = Sprite("one.png")
one.rect.x = 55
one.rect.y = 410
two.rect.x = 155
two.rect.y = 410
three.rect.x = 255
three.rect.y = 410
four.rect.x = 355
four.rect.y = 410
lvlselect.add(one)
lvlselect.add(two)
lvlselect.add(three)
lvlselect.add(four)

#OTHER
back = Sprite("back.png")
back.rect.x = 0
back.rect.y = 12
back_butt.add(back)

#PLAYER
player = Player("player.png")
player_list.add(player)
all_sprites_list.add(player)
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace (error message) as it tells us (and you) exactly which line you get the error on.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\codys\Desktop\LARP\LARP_1.py", line 149, in <module>
    two.rect.x = 155
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: @CodySoloveoff you should add it to the question instead of the comments because as you can see then in the comments it is not that readable, you can [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

You need tp create *Sprite* objects for `two`, `three` and `for`, like you do it for `one`:

```py
one = Sprite("one.png")
two = Sprite("two.png")
three = Sprite("three.png")
four = Sprite("four.png")
```

You don't need the *Surface* objects at all:

<s>`one = pygame.image.load("one.png").convert_alpha()`</s>
<s>`two = pygame.image.load("two.png").convert_alpha()`</s>
<s>`three = pygame.image.load("three.png").convert_alpha()`</s>
<s>`four = pygame.image.load("four.png").convert_alpha()`</s>